# Can't get try and except to work in Python

Tags: python, except

I have a bit Caesar Cipher code and cant get the try/except to work. All it does is repeat up to the first input. It does not display "INCORRECT INPUT". What can I do to fix this?

```
while True:
    try:
        encrypt = raw_input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a message? (E/D) : ").lower()
        print("")
        if encrypt == 'e':
            print("ENCRYPTION: Due to the nature of the Caesar Cipher, Numbers and Symbols will 
                  be removed. Please represent numbers as the word...")
            print("I.E. - 7 should be entered as 'seven'. ")
            print("")
            sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence : ").lower()
            newString = ''
            validLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
            space = []
            for char in sentence:
                if char in validLetters or char in space:
                    newString += char
            shift = input("Please enter your shift : ")
            resulta = []
            for ch in newString:
                x = ord(ch)
                x = x+shift
                resulta.append(chr(x if 97 <= x <= 122 else 96+x%122) if ch != ' ' else ch)
            print sentence
            print("")
            print("Your encryption is :")
            print("")
            print ''.join(resulta)
        if encrypt == 'd':
            print("DECRYPTION : PUNCTUATION WILL NOT BE DECRYPTED")
            print("")
            sentence = raw_input("Please enter an encrypted message : ").lower()
            newString = ''
            validLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
            for char in sentence:
                if char in validLetters:
                newString += char
            shift = input("Please enter your shift : ")
            decryptshift = 26 - shift
            resulta = []
            for ch in newString:
                x = ord(ch)
                x = x + decryptshift
                resulta.append(chr(x if 97 <= x <= 122 else 96+x%122) if ch != ' ' else ch)
            print sentence
            print("")
            print("Your encryption is :")
            print("")
            print ''.join(resulta)
        if encrypt == 'q':
            break
    except:
        print("")
        print("INCORRECT INPUT!")
        print("")
    continue
```

I've tried various locations for both try and except...I am lost. Thanks in advance!

Comment: whoa ... __dont use try/except like this__ ... only one or two lines should be in your try block ... so you can tell at which point you fail... also your except is empty so it will catch all errors including errors you probably dont want to catch

Comment: Is there anything in there that raises an Exception?

Comment: So use try for maybe each IF statement?

Comment: Use `try` for things that are likely to raise an exception, or write them in a way that they won't raise an exception.

Comment: Would an Else be more appropriate?

Comment: as a side note, maybe break out encrypt and decrypt as functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try..except` blocks are used if you or the system raise an exception. The `except` block will not be executed if the `try` block finishes successfully. In your case it does, your program simply does not go into the `if` blocks.

To get the expected result, rewrite the if statements as follows:

```
    if encrypt == 'e':
        ...
    elif encrypt == 'd':
        ...
    elif encrypt == 'q':
        break
    else:
        print("")
        print("INCORRECT INPUT!")
        print("")
```

This way, you combine all the conditions, and have a "default" statement. The `else` after `elif`s will enter if none of the previous `elif`s AND the first `if` are entered (which is basically saying that none of the conditions are true).

If you don't use `elif` and use only `if` (as in your original code), the condition chain is broken and the `else` at the end will catch all cases in which `encrypt != "q"`, even if it is "e" or "d".

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and it seems ok, after I fixed the mismatched identation here:

```
      if char in validLetters:
      newString += char
```

to this:

```
      if char in validLetters:
          newString += char
```

I got the following output:

```
Please enter a sentence : test
Please enter your shift : 

INCORRECT INPUT!
```

Answer (score 0):

this is OT from the original question , but

```
result = raw_input("Enter Q, D, or E")
while result.lower() not in ["q","d","e"]:
      result = raw_input("Invalid Response! Enter Q,D, or E:")
#now you know result is one of q d or e
```

is probably a better way to get your input